# upgrade datastax-agent for opscenter RHEL isolated nodes from tarbell

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

A colleague installed a 3 node DSE cluster.
When bringing up Opscenter on the seed node, we get an alert that the agent requires an upgrade from 5.2.0 to 5.2.2 and the agent is not installed on the two other nodes.
Because of environmental restrictions, We do not have the internet accessibility or root credentials to perform the automated upgrade/install from Opscenter.  I downloaded and unpacked the 5.2.2 agent tarbell and the latest Opscenter.

Where do I overlay 5.2.0 contents with 5.2.2 to manually perform the upgrade with only SU access via the command line?  On the non-seed nodes, I started the agents manually.

Non-seed:

```
root      8362     1  2 Nov30 ?        03:36:33 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.51-1.b16.el6_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Xmx128M -Djclouds.mpu.parts.magnitude=100000 -Djclouds.mpu.parts.size=16777216 -Dopscenter.ssl.trustStore=ssl/agentKeyStore -Dopscenter.ssl.keyStore=ssl/agentKeyStore -Dopscenter.ssl.keyStorePassword=opscenter -Dagent-pidfile=./datastax-agent.pid -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./conf/log4j.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./conf/kerberos.config -jar datastax-agent-5.2.`2-standalone.jar ./conf/address.yaml
```

Seed:

```
497       4375     1  2 Nov30 ?        03:42:23 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.51-1.b16.el6_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Xmx128M -Djclouds.mpu.parts.magnitude=100000 -Djclouds.mpu.parts.size=16777216 -Dopscenter.ssl.trustStore=/var/lib/datastax-agent/ssl/agentKeyStore -Dopscenter.ssl.keyStore=/var/lib/datastax-agent/ssl/agentKeyStore -Dopscenter.ssl.keyStorePassword=opscenter -Dagent-pidfile=/var/run/datastax-agent/datastax-agent.pid -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./conf/log4j.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./conf/kerberos.config -jar datastax-agent-5.2.0-standalone.jar /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml
```

We are completely new to DSE and RHEL.

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 cassandra cassandra 4096 Sep 17 12:20 datastax-agent
drwxr-xr-x   7 root      root      4096 Nov 30 14:31 datastax-agent-5.2.2
drwxr-xr-x   4 root      root      4096 Nov 30 14:31 datastax-agent-old
```

datastax-agent:

```
total 24836
drwxrwxr-x   7 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 17 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x. 95 root      root          4096 Dec  1 17:08 ..
drwxrwxr-x   3 cassandra cassandra     4096 Nov 16 13:16 bin
drwxrwxr-x   2 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 17 12:20 conf
-rw-rw-r--   1 cassandra cassandra 25402316 Jul 14 12:19 datastax-agent-5.2.0-standalone.jar
drwxrwxr-x   2 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 17 12:20 doc
drwxrwxr-x   2 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 17 12:20 ssl
drwxrwxr-x   3 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 17 12:20 tmp
```

datastax-agent-5.2.2:

```
total 25044
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root     4096 Dec  1 17:08 .
drwxr-xr-x. 95 root root     4096 Dec  1 17:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root     4096 Dec  1 17:08 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Dec  1 17:08 conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 25608470 Dec  1 17:08 datastax-agent-5.2.2-standalone.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root root        5 Dec  1 18:06 datastax-agent.pid
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Dec  1 17:08 doc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Dec  1 17:08 log
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Dec  1 17:08 ssl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install DSE? rpm, tarball or standalone installer? Either way, to get the new agent in place, the only thing you need is the new jar file, so drop the one from the tar ball into the location where you see datastax-agent-5.2.0-standalone.jar (which unfortunately varies based upon the install method you used, hence my question above :-). Move the old jar out of the way and restart the agent process /etc/init.d/datastax-agent stop followed by /etc/init.d/datastax-agent start).

Comment: thanks very much for your help... it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade OpsCenter Agent installed from tarball, simply extract that tarball to the same directory the agent was installed before and remove the old jar file (`datastax-agent-5.2.0-standalone.jar` in this case).

Comment: thanks ... that was a quick fix to swap the old 5.2.0 jar with the new 5.2.2 jar.  After stopping the datastax-agent and opscenterd ... it worked perfectly after restarting.

Comment: Great, glad we got this resolved :-). Happy to help, let me know if there are any other issues.